# Compute the values of current row and prev row in Postgres SQL

Tags: postgresql

Good day! I need help in computing the 7day callback interval based on category on a given month. the out put will be the total call back in all category.
 I really nead help big thaanks!

**sample table:**

```
mif(category) |date_started
1             | 2017/01/5
1             | 2017/01/11     * count as 7 day interval cat1 #1<br>
1             | 2017/01/23
2             | 2017/01/5 
2             | 2017/01/7      * count as 7 day interval in cat2 #1 <br>
2             | 2017/01/9      * count as 7 day interval in cat2 #2<br>
3             | 2017/01/5
3             | 2017/01/23 
3             | 2017/01/25     * count as 7 day interval in cat3 #2<br/><br>
```

The final output is = 4 (total of all callbacks in all category)
I already created a function with for loop to loop each mif(category)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.service_call_back(IN i_month integer, IN i_year integer, OUT o_val integer)
Returns integer
LANGUAGE plpgsql
as $function$
declare
v_looper integer;
v_counter integer;
begin
   for v_looper in select distinct mif from service_report where  extract(month from date_time_started) = i_month AND extract(year from date_time_started) = I_year order by mif

loop

#category

end loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you use a query like the following to calculate both counts at the same time. Although you didn't explain what the 7 day callback means by deduction it appears to be any row where the number of days between then is 7 or less, so that can be facilitated using the lag function to give us the previous date and then calculate the number of days.

Please note that it is better for performance to compare stored dates to a calculated date instead of converting every stored date into a month value and a year value.

select 
      mif, mif_count, call_back_7s, sum(call_back_7s) over() sum_callbacks
from (
      select 
            mif
          , count(*) mif_count
          , count(
               case when extract(days from date_time_started - prev_call_date) <= 7 then 1 end 
                 ) call_back_7s
      from (
              select
                    *
                  , lag(date_time_started,1) over(partition by mif order by date_time_started) prev_call_date
              from service_report 
              where  date_time_started >= make_date(2017, 1, 1)
              AND date_time_started < make_date(2017, 1, 1) + interval '1 month'
              ) sr
      group by mif
    ) d

To make the dates with your curent paramters just place then into the make_date function like so:

```
make_date(i_year , i_month, 1)
```

**[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/48245/14/0)**:

```
| mif | mif_count | call_back_7s | sum_callbacks |
|-----|-----------|--------------|---------------|
|   1 |         3 |            1 |             4 |
|   2 |         3 |            2 |             4 |
|   3 |         3 |            1 |             4 |
```

Comment: It worked !! and I have a follow up question, how can I count all the callbacks in all the mif ?  ex. 4 (based on demo)

Comment: added another column, places 4 on each row